# meaning of "variable is local to the function, now the loop"

Tags: javascript

in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) mozilla article, the following phase is used

## Parameters

### **variable**

Variable to iterate over property values, optionally declared with the var keyword. This variable is local to the function, not to the loop.

to describe a foreach...in loop

```
for each (variable in object) {
  statement
}
```

I know that it's written that this loop is deprecated, but I'm just interested in the vocabulary. What does it mean that "the variable is local to the function, not the loop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can access the variable in the function, outside of the loop. See [variable scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how this is practically useful? If I'm doing the `foreach...in` loop, by the time I get to the remainder of the function, `variable` is going to have been incremented to the length of `object`. So I can then on the next like say something like `console.log(variable)` and do something useful with it somehow?

Comment: It'll give you the value of the last thing the loop iterated over. Not sure of it's use but if you didn't know this and used the variable elsewhere you might be in for a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was actually just a little bit further on that very same site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

JavaScript has what is called "Function Scope", which means variables (if declared with the var keyword) are scoped to the function. They are only accessible from within that Function.

Some other languages have "block scope" in which case the scope of the variable would be constrained to the block of code (which would be the part in between the brackets {} )

I hope the link helps.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have **block statement scope**. I'll refer you back to the Mozilla Javascript Guide on variables and scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables).

Javascript is a funky language with the good and bad parts, you should check out the good parts by [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/), if you want to learn more about the ins and outs of Javascript.

Comment: Mozilla's JavaScript has block scope. This is why it needs to clarify. That `for each-in` syntax is specific to Mozilla and isn't standard. If the loop is formed as `for each(let variable in object)`, the `variable` would be scoped to the block.